# Why and When Twilio removes the error message from the receiver service?

Tags: xml, rest, voip, twilio, twilio-twiml

Trying to call an invalid number I found that when we use the *Dial* as normal to call a number like:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number>3134610537</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

or

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        3134610537
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

we can hear the error message from the provider telling as that the number is invalid or is not longer on service.

But when we use the *url* parameter inside of the *Number* tag we don't get that message:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number url="http://a.url.here/">3134610537</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

I see the same problem using the REST API.

Why is that?
And when does it happen?

Dial should be consistent with the REST API call, thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a support ticket in Twilio since this question doesn't have answers yet.

From Twilio Support:

> That's a good question. That's one of the inconsistencies in the
>   Twilio API with regards to "early media" or the audio the carrier
>   sends before the call is connected.
>
> With `<Number url>` Twilio plays fake ringing until the call recipient
>   accepts the call, so the early audio is masked.
>
> With REST API calls the early audio is not captured because the
>   recording only begins when the call begins.
>
> I'm sorry for the confusion and the inconsistency. Please let us know
>   if you have any other questions.
>
> Alex Chan
>
> Twilio Customer Support
>
> www.twilio.com